# How to use git to implement a simple versioning system?

Tags: django, git, version-control

I wish to create an interface where the user can list, upload and modify existing files. The user should also be able see the past snapshots of their files and permanently revert to a past snapshot if they so desire. My use case is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972652/how-to-code-a-simple-versioning-system). I am thinking of something like GitHub.com, but with a very simple interface that anyone will be able to understand (e.g. web interface only, one branch only, ...)

What are the options available to create this kind of simple versioning system? Or should I need to integrate git into my Django project? (pointers on how to do this would be appreciated. It's my first time doing this.)

Comment: `but with a very simple interface` ... while the interface might be simple, implementing is going to be a _big_ job.  Rather than recreating something like GitHub or Bitbucket, could you maybe explain why these existing tools don't meet your needs?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is mainly because GitHub cannot be used directly on my website. How is it possible to integrate GitHub with my website? (especially when the every user's files are to be private?)

Answer (score 0):

The function of git versioning systems is usually separate with other functions on your website, you’d better **use github/bitbucket directly or add a link to github/bitbucket on your website**.

Develop the interface of versioning system is time consuming and it hard to develop the whole functions as github/bitcket. If you want to have a try, [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) may help.